# Do bundled dependencies pull in their own dependencies from their package.json?

Tags: node.js, dependencies, npm, nodejitsu

I'm deploying my app on Nodejitsu and I have a custom module that I have npm linked. I've added this module to my bundled dependencies but the deployment throws issues that it can't find the modules that the bundled dependency is dependent on.

These dependencies are listed in its package.json but for some reason aren't getting pulled in.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have these dependencies been published on npm?

Answer (score 3):

If you ever get stuck in something like this please feel free to drop by #nodejitsu at freenode.

Answering your question:

> An array containing a list of package names you have bundled in your
>   package.
>
> The convention here is to make sure your bundled dependencies exist in
>   the node_modules/ folder.
>
> Packages listed in bundleDependencies will now remain locked into the
>   version contained in the node_modules/ folder.

Source: http://package.json.jit.su

You can also add git repos as dependencies:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "dependencies": {
    "private-repo": "git+ssh://git@github.com:my-account/node-private-repo.git#v0.0.1",
  }
}
```

Source: http://debuggable.com/posts/private-npm-modules:4e68cc7d-1ac4-42d9-995a-343dcbdd56cb

Comment: I have added my local fork as a bundled dependency but none of it's dependencies get pulled down when I try to deploy. Errors are thrown that they are missing.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but I feel like Nodejitsu use exactly what is in folder from
the bundled dependencies. It simply copy every files and never run npm install on 
them.
After all, that's bundled dependencies, one could expect them to be self 
contained.